# Rails3 Active Admin - How to filter only records that meet all checked items in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a one-to-many associaton of user to network model. The relevant parts of my schema information is as follows.

```
# == Schema Information      
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :integer         not null, primary key
#  name                   :string(255)

#
# Table name: networks
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  uid        :string(255)
#  name   :string(255)
#  pub_url    :string(255)
```

I want to filter out users who have specific multiple networks using the name property of the network model. For example if I check facebook and foursquare as filters, I want to get back users who have connected both facebook and foursquare. My current implementation is to pass an array containing the names of networks a user can add as displayed below.

```
filter :networks_name, :as => :check_boxes,
:collection => %w(facebook twitter foursquare linkedin)
```

This however uses an OR condition for the filters which retrieves users with any of the checked items. What I actually want to get is users who meet all the checked items.
What's the right way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveAdmin uses meta_search for its filters (https://github.com/ernie/meta_search):

```
filter :networks_name_all,
  :as => :check_boxes,
  :collection => %w(facebook twitter foursquare linkedin)
```

And in your user model:

```
scope :networks_names_all_in, -> names {
  names.reduce(scoped) do |scope, name|
    subquery = User.select('`users`.`id`').
      joins(:networks).
      where('networks.name = ?', name)
    scope.where("`users`.`id` IN (#{subquery.to_sql})")
  end
}
search_methods :networks_name_all_in
```

This will create a nice single SQL query for you, with proper joins and where conditions.

For example:

```
User.networks_name_all_in(["facebook", "twitter"])
```

will generate the following SQL request:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `users`.`id` IN (SELECT `users`.`id`
                       FROM `users`
                       INNER JOIN `networks`
                       ON `networks`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
                       WHERE `networks`.`name` = 'facebook')
  AND `users`.`id` IN (SELECT `users`.`id`
                       FROM `users`
                       INNER JOIN `networks`
                       ON `networks`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
                       WHERE `networks`.`name` = 'twitter')
```

**Update:** Added functional scope.

**Update 2:** Make scope resilient to scope merging problems.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. However I think you left out the the part I needed most to solve it. What I need most is how to query for users with all of the specified networks. From the above code it will be the part in the curly bracket where you omitted. Were you able to figure that out?

Comment: Yes, that would be the part in the curly braces. I thought your main problem was the ActiveAdmin part, not the SQL query itself. Give me a minute, and I'll complete my answer.

Comment: OK I think it's getting closer. The functional scope works as expected when tried in the console. However, the query strangely doesn't yield the expected result when used as an activeadmin filter. I'm using the exact filter expression shown in your answer.

Comment: Could you check in the logs what kind of SQL query the activeadmin filter generates?

Comment: Sure. It looks like the filter uses just the last checked value. Checking twitter and facebook for example produces this in the logs; SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `users`.`id` IN (SELECT `users`.`id`
                       FROM `users`
                       INNER JOIN `networks`
                       ON `networks`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
                       WHERE `networks`.`name` = 'facebook')
Similar to the query produced by;     User.networks_name_all_in(["facebook"]).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19752/discussion-between-dantastic-and-jean-louis-giordano)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a query that does not break when used in ActiveAdmin